# Parallelize a collection with Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to parallelize a collection with Spark and the example in the documentation doesn't seem to work:

```
List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
JavaRDD<Integer> distData = sc.parallelize(data);
```

I'm creating a list of `LabeledPoint`s from records each of which contain data points (`double[]`) and a label (defaulted: true/false).

```
 public List<LabeledPoint> createLabeledPoints(List<ESRecord> records) {
    List<LabeledPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ESRecord rec : records) {

        points.add(new LabeledPoint(
                rec.defaulted ? 1.0 : 0.0, Vectors.dense(rec.toDataPoints())));
    }
    return points;
}

public void test(List<ESRecord> records) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SVM Classifier Example");
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    List<LabeledPoint> points = createLabeledPoints(records);        
    JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> data = sc.parallelize(points);
    ...
 }
```

The function signature of parallelize is no longer taking one parameter, here is how it looks in spark-mllib_2.11 v1.3.0: `sc.parallelize(seq, numSlices, evidence$1)`

So any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Java, you should use `JavaSparkContext`.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html